# Find items having missing bitstreams in DSpace 6.0/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, repository, cleanup

I tried to export a collection through the dspace packager but that leads me to a java exception:

Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/dspace/dspace/assetstore/24/53/70/24537062703407880406826961992454636643 (There is no such file or directory)

I want to find (and possibly to clean) all these references between items and missing files in the assetstore. Can someone please give me some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I managed to solve the problem. Probably it may be even better, but here's how I solved it:
we exported to a text file (internal_id.txt) the paths of all bitstreams using the following query:

select
    substring(b.internal_id for 2) || '/' || substring(b.internal_id from 3 for 2) || '/' || substring(b.internal_id from 5 for 2) || '/' || b.internal_id as bitstream_path
from
    bitstream b

After that I checked the existence of those bistreams in the assetstore with this little script:

```
#!/bin/sh

homedspace=/home/dspace
assetd=$homedspace/assetstore

for i in `cat $homedspace/internal_id.txt`;
do
  bitstr="$assetd/$i"
  if [ ! -f $fbitstr ]; then
    echo "$i"
  fi;
done
```

To get details about the records that have missing bitstreams I used the following query

```
select
    ob.uuid
    ,h.handle
    ,i.item_id
    ,bfr.short_description
    ,mv.text_value
    ,substring(b.internal_id for 2) || '/' || substring(b.internal_id from 3 for 2) || '/' || substring(b.internal_id from 5 for 2) || '/' || b.internal_id as bitstream_path
from
    dspaceobject ob
left join handle h on
    ob.uuid = h.resource_id 
left join item i on
    i.uuid = ob.uuid
left join bitstream b on
    b.uuid = ob.uuid
left join bitstreamformatregistry bfr on
    bfr.bitstream_format_id = b.bitstream_format_id
join metadatavalue mv on
    mv.dspace_object_id = ob.uuid
    and b.internal_id in 
    ('114010604776142507469236848335815822008',
    '144380007015254523440612284014079661640',
    '72819755632666247567002874213191474609')
    order by b.internal_id
```

I hope this can helps somebody...